# Swift: copying files gives Cocoa Error 262

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to move my files up a level in some random directory in the default Documents directory. But when copying, Swift gave me the error Cocoa Error 262: `NSFileReadUnsupportedSchemeError`. Why did I get this error? I ran a quick search and pretty much everyone who'd encountered this problem was trying to copy files out of the camera roll, but I'm not. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Code here:

```
private func copyFilesInDirectory(fromDir: String, toDirectory toDir: String, withCompletionHandler handler: ()->()){
    println("from: \(fromDir)\nto: \(toDir)")
    var error: NSError?

    var contents = fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(fromDir, error: &error)
    if let dirContents = contents{
        let enumerator = (dirContents as NSArray).objectEnumerator()

        while let file = enumerator.nextObject() as? String{
            let filePath = fromDir.stringByAppendingString("/\(file)")
            println("copying \(filePath)")
            if(fileManager.copyItemAtURL(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)!, toURL: NSURL(string: toDir)!, error: &error)){
                println("COPIED")
            }
            else{
                println("COPY ERROR: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
        handler()
    }
}
```

and here's the log if anyone's interested:

```
    from: /Users/dolce/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/05566649-BABB-44BE-BE6F-AFF7B41E3065/data/Containers/Data/Application/F5A83C94-C177-4826-BDD5-3A50E7508239/Documents/Hello/tmp
    to: /Users/dolce/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/05566649-BABB-44BE-BE6F-AFF7B41E3065/data/Containers/Data/Application/F5A83C94-C177-4826-BDD5-3A50E7508239/Documents/Hello
    copying /Users/dolce/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/05566649-BABB-44BE-BE6F-AFF7B41E3065/data/Containers/Data/Application/F5A83C94-C177-4826-BDD5-3A50E7508239/Documents/Hello/tmp/test.png
    COPY ERROR: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 262.)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `toURL` parameter of `copyItemAtURL()` must not be the destination
*directory*, but the URL of the destination *file*. This can be
created with

```
let destPath = toDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(file)
```

You should also replace

```
let filePath = fromDir.stringByAppendingString("/\(file)")
```

with

```
let filePath = fromDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(file)
```

There is also a `copyItemAtPath()` method which saves you from
converting the paths to URLs.

Comment: Should've asked an hour earlier, could've used that time on something more constructive than blindly debugging...

Answer (score 0):

On an iOS device, the simple answer is you can't do that. On the simulator things are little different. What you're probably dealing with is file permissions on the directory you're  trying to write to.

As a general rule on iOS, you can write to the designated directories like the documents/caches and **nothing** else.